# Using OpenLayers 5 examples, error:Failed to resolve module specifier "rbush"

Tags: dictionary, openlayers

I'm trying to make a simple example work on my local environment. I want to make a map on my website, but once I downloaded the necessary files I've got strange problems. First, I had to add for the example script link the 'type="module"' code, which is already made me crazy. Nobody tests these applications, or my environment is so special? Why are they even using the import tag, if it's not working in the most used browser like a charm?! After I extended the example code and changed the import links to be fine for my environment (ol/Map.js to /ol/Map.js), now I've got this error you can read in the title. Failed to resolve module specifier "rbush". What can I do? I have no idea. There must be a main point I have missed. The example (https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/simple.html) works fine online on openlayers.org, but If I follow the instructions It don't on my end. Why?

Answer (score 5):

OpenLayers 5.1.3 is meant to be used with the [npm package manager](https://www.npmjs.com/) as described here:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html

To use it without including the dependencies and "building" it, see the [quick start page in the documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/quickstart.html):

> Put a map on a page
>   Below you'll find a complete working example. Create a new file, copy in the contents below, and open in a browser:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.1.3/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
    
    .map {
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.1.3/build/ol.js"></script>
  <title>OpenLayers example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
      ],
      view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
        zoom: 4
      })
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[working example of the "simple" example](http://www.geocodezip.com/OL_5.1.3_simple.html)